# How to calculate the log loss metric in scala/spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-science, xgboost

I have trained a binary classifier (`XGBoostClassifier`) model, and have two columns in my result dataframe: `PREDICTED_COL` and `TARGET_COL`. I can calculate, for example, the areaUnderROC by:

```
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(df.select(col(PREDICTED_COL), col(TARGET_COL)).rdd.map(row => (row.getDouble(0), row.getInt(1).toDouble)))
val auc = metrics.areaUnderROC()
```

However, there is no corresponding/easy way to calculate the log loss metric. How to do that?

**Note**: I tried to use 
**org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.loss.LogLoss** but that function does not take any parameters (e.g. my PREDICTED_COL and TARGET_COL), so not sure how to use it.

Here is the LogLoss formula:
[image: LogLoss formula]

Answer (score 1):

You can just implement the formula:

```scala
val df_ll = df.withColumn("logloss", -($"target_col" * log($"predicted_col") + (lit(1) - $"target_col") * log(lit(1) - $"predicted_col")))
```

Note that we use only built in functions from spark.sql.functions which means that we get quite good performance (better than UDF)

Comment: Thanks! The only remaining part is then to compute the mean of the sample logloss (which is what we get from your code, i.e., a column of doubles), something like this: `val loglossA = df_ll.agg(mean("logloss").alias("ll")).collect()`  does that look right?

Answer (score 0):

So here is a handy function to calculate the log-loss given a dataframe (`TARGET_COL` is the ground truth aka label, and `PREDICTED_COL` is the prediction returned by the model):

```
def calcualteLogLoss (df: Dataset[Row]): Double = {
    val df2 = df.withColumn("logloss",
      col(TARGET_COL).multiply(lit(-1))
        .multiply(log(col(PREDICTED_COL)))
      .minus(
        lit(1.0).minus(col(TARGET_COL))
          .multiply(log(lit(1).minus(col(PREDICTED_COL))))
      )
    )

    // calculate desired logloss as average of all samples
    val loglossA = df2.agg(mean("logloss").alias("ll")).collect()
    var logloss = -1d
    if (loglossA != null && loglossA.length > 0){
      val loglossB = loglossA.head
      if (loglossB != null && loglossB.length > 0 && loglossB.get(0) != null) {
        logloss = loglossB.getDouble(0)
      }
    }

    logloss
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple function can be used to get log loss.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def logloss(predictions, label_column):
        """
        function for calculation of log loss
        :param spark.DataFrame predictions : model predicted spark dataframe
        :param string label_column : column name containing true labels
        :return float
        """
        get_first_element = F.udf(lambda v:float(v[1]), FloatType())
        predictions = predictions.select(F.col(label_column).alias("label"), "probability")
        predictions = predictions.withColumn("true_prediction_probability", \
                                               get_first_element(F.col("probability"))).drop("probability")

        predictions = predictions.withColumn("logloss", -(F.col("label") * F.log(F.col("true_prediction_probability")) + \
                             (F.lit(1) - F.col("label")) * F.log(F.lit(1) - F.col("true_prediction_probability"))))
        log_loss = predictions.select(F.mean("logloss")).collect()[0][0]

        return log_loss
```